# Subversion commands to add new user and grant all permissions

Tags: svn, commit, command, smartsvn

Currently, I am not able to commit with the SVN user I added. I tried by manually editing the `svnserve.conf` and `passwd` files. I did the following.

- Added a line, `harry = harrysecret`, in `passwd`
- Uncommented the line `password-db = passwd` in `svnserve.conf`
- Added a system user, `harry`, with password = harrysecret as follows:-

  useradd harry
     passwd harry

I am using SVN+SSH protocol and am able to checkout, update but, while committing I am getting the error

```
Commit failed - Can't create directory 'path/to/repository/db/transactions/1852-1.txn' Permission denied
```

But, with `root` user I am able to commit.

I googled to find commands and found the following.

```
sudo htpasswd -m /etc/subversion/svn-auth-file sally
New password: *******
Re-type new password: *******
Adding password for user sally
```

(http://www.divvun.no/doc/infra/system/addsvn-users.html)

It did not work for me.

http://wiki.site5.com/SVN/Subversion_(SVN)_Setup_Guide#Setup_a_new_SVN_user_account

```
    cd ~
    mkdir .ssh
    chmod 700 .ssh
    touch .ssh/authorized_keys
    chmod 600 .ssh/authorized_keys
```

http://help.joyent.com/index.php?id=55&pg=kb.page

- cd to the domain’s `etc/` directory
- with any text editor, edit ‘svn-access.conf’ by adding a
  ‘permission line’ for ‘newuser’ to an
  existing repository (repositories are
  created in webmin)
- add a password for ‘newuser’ to the svn.basic.passwd file with bash$
  htpasswd svn.basic.passwd newuser (it
  will prompt twice for the new
  password)

But, I do not have svn-access.conf in the `/etc` directory.

Are there sure shot ways to add users with all permissions? I need to instruct someone to do the same on a remote server.

Comment: Wile I will most certainly be unable to help you anyway, you might want to state how you access your repository. Are you using SVN's built-in `svn` protocol server? Or an Apache server? Are you using ssh tunneling?...

Comment: I am using svn+ssh protocol. I faced the problem after hosting the repository in a remote server. So, I tried to create the same situation by creating the repository in the local system and trying to commit. And I have the same situation - not able to commit in both places

Comment: Like Vasco said, I verified that adding SVN users explicitly is not needed. Just adding system users, adding them to group and granting 770 permission to the group works. Am I correct? Why is it so? Anybody?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I never added a user in SVN. Try CHMOD 777 for all rights.

Comment: chmod 770 sorry (group write permission), 775 still gives commit error

Comment: Like Vasco said, I verified that adding SVN users explicitly is not needed. Just adding system users, adding them to group and granting 770 permission to the group works. Am I correct? Why is it so? Anybody?